# Adjustbox on a landscape page makes a table too small

Tags: tables, scaling, adjustbox

I am trying to use adjustbox to scale down a table that is too large for a landscape page, but when I use it, the scaled table is much smaller than it needs to be relative to the size of the page. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Below is an example that shows the issue. The same table is shown both using adjustbox and without.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,pdflscape,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text. some filler text.  

\begin{table}[t]

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textheight}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
\toprule
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Women} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Men} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                     & Person-  &    & Person-  &  \\
                     &  month  &  Unique & month  &  Unique \\
Sample restrictions  & records  &  individuals & records  &  individuals \\
\midrule
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx          & xxxxxx & xxxxx & xxxxx & xxxxx \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% now same table without adjustbox
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
\toprule
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Women} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Men} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                     & Person-  &    & Person-  &  \\
                     &  month  &  Unique & month  &  Unique \\
Sample restrictions  & records  &  individuals & records  &  individuals \\
\midrule
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx          & xxxxxx & xxxxx & xxxxx & xxxxx \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> max width=\textheight}

`lscape` sets `\textheight` locally to be the new *height* but you want the local *width* so use `\linewidth` instead.

Comment: This works well. I should have mentioned that I had tried using `\textwidth` instead of `\textheight`, but got the same result. Why does `\linewidth` work, then?

Comment: @ScottB I switched `\textheight`, `\linewidth` and `\columnwidth` to the new orientation but I left `\textwidth` referring to the original width as `lscape` keeps the page head and foot and several page head styles use `\textwidth` in their layout and would break if it changed.